# how to iterate rows and append column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe(csv file) which looks like:

```
Name   Apple  Banana  Carrot Mango

Adam   false   false  true   true
James  false   true   true   false
Jessie false   false  true   true
```

I need to iterate over rows and append column name with 'true' value in  a string with output like:

```
Carrot,Mango
Banana,Carrot
Carrot,Mango
```

Here's how i tried to do it (which is not working):

```
data = pandas.read_csv("filename.csv")
df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
columns = df.columns.values
str = ""
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for c in columns:
        if c == True:
            str.append(c)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I don't get any output at all, something must be wrong here.. thanks

Comment: by the way having a variable named `str` is not recommended, this will hide the `str` type

Comment: you really should not name your variable `str`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using Pandas.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: data = pd.DataFrame({"Apple": [False, False, False], "Banana": [False, True, False], "Carrot": [True, True, True], "Mango": [True, False, True]}, columns=["Apple", "Banana", "Carrot", "Mango"])

In [3]: true_columns = []

In [4]: for index, row in data.iterrows():
   ...:     true_col_list = [col for col in data.columns if row[col]]
   ...:     true_columns.append(",".join(true_col_list))
   ...:

In [5]: data["true_columns"] = true_columns

In [6]: data
Out[6]:
   Apple Banana Carrot  Mango   true_columns
0  False  False   True   True   Carrot,Mango
1  False   True   True  False  Banana,Carrot
2  False  False   True   True   Carrot,Mango
```

Comment: hehe :) better than my solution :P ... I figured there was a good way to do it with pandas... I just havent worked with pandas enough

Comment: hello jack! i need to read the csv file and the columns is huge..i just put four columns here as a sample...thanks

Comment: Yes, and that's okay. Just do the same `for` loop on the data frame that you grabbed from the CSV. I instantiated the data frame manually just to have some data to code against.

Comment: How would i read the data with large no of columns? It don't seem to work for some reason..

Comment: Look. I'm trying to help you. Phrases like "don't seem to work for some reason" are useless to me. What isn't working? Do you get an error message? Do you get unexpected output?

Comment: Well..i am not getting the desired output...i get the list of whole columns in the csv file...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Are you saying that every column name shows up in every row in the new column you're constructing?

Comment: yes jack when i do print(true_columns), it shows all the columns from the csv file..as a matter of fact i'm trying to save the output in a new file..thnks

Comment: Well, if you constructed `true_columns` via the `for` loop over `data.iterrows()` as above, the only way that you'll get every column name in an entry of `true_columns` is if every column has a value of `True` for that row... Not sure what else to tell you.

Comment: thanks Jack for the help i got the output i needed..i had to read the csv file little differently..i used data = pandas.read_csv("name.csv", index_col=[0,1], skipinitialspace=True)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know that you really need pandas for this

```
with open("my.csv") as f:
    headers = next(f).split(",")[1:]
    lines = (line for line in f if line.strip())        
    for line in lines:
        for hdr,itm in zip(headers,line.split(",")[1:]:
           if "true" in itm:
               print hdr
```

Comment: hi joran! i get error:   lines = (line for line in f in line.strip())        
NameError: name 'line' is not defined